# Laravel : Home page route doesn't work in my server

Tags: laravel, laravel-7

when my url is empty on my server, it doesn't display any content on my server yet, it works perfectly locally ... Do you have an idea ?
I tried a lot of things with my routes but it doesn't change anything, the problem must be elsewhere...

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});
```

Or

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return redirect()->route('home');
});
```

Comment: if you get white blank on your server, please check your PHP version whether suitable with your laravel

Answer (score 0):

I think this happens for the public folder is not pointing correctly

you can also check something like :

1. your base URL (domain) should point to the public folder.
2. Use Absolute path like `Route::get('/test/abc', 'Groupcontroller@index');`
3. Also, you need to check Conontrooller namespace.
4. check .htacess file

Comment: I don't get it because it works on absolutely every other page.

Comment: can you share your project folder structure ?